# Compare 2 values in 2 different work sheets and automatically copy a range of values

Tags: compare

I've been trying to do this for some time but I keep hitting a roadblock.

I have a sheet in Excel that has a column by name -  Index with values 1 to 10.
I have columns F to U that has some data for each index value.

I created a new sheet with columns Index and remaining columns similar to first sheet. 
I want a macro so that when I type 2 as Index value, it will automatically populate values from Sheet 1 - columns F to U corresponding to index value 2 to new sheet. This should work for any new index value added in Sheet 1.

I tried doing a formula but it did not work.

Any ideas?

Example

Sheet 1

Columns    Index

```
         1       q w e r s t u v a b c d e f g h
         2       a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p
```

Sheet 2

When I type value 2 under Column Index in Sheet 2, it must populate corresponding values from a to p automatically.

2   a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is going to be a good solution for you, but it does work.

In Sheet 2, lets say row 1 is reserved for column headings, and `A2` is where you put your index value, then put the following formula in `F2` on sheet 2 and copy across to `U2`:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!F2:F11,Sheet2!$A$2-1,0,1,1)
```

For the first column (`F`), this references the `F` column in sheet 1, and uses the index you type into sheet 2, to move to the correct row and copy the value from sheet 1 to sheet 2.

Edit.. Rereading your question, I modified my solution slightly:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!F:F,Sheet2!$A$2,0,1,1)
```

This allows for adding any number of additional indices, and so long as the indices are all in order from 1 to whatever, the behaviour you are expecting in sheet 2 will work. Note that subtracting 1 is not necessary, as offset 0 is the row reserved for column headings.

Comment: This works if there are consecutive index values in Sheet 2. If I have 1 as the index value and next value is 3, it still displays the values of index 2 from Sheet 1. Any ideas? I was thinking this might require a macro.

Comment: Try this:

=INDIRECT("Sheet1!F"&ROW(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,MATCH($A$2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0))),TRUE)


You can't simply copy it from f2 throught to U2, because the F in the string (Sheet1!F) won't change. There could be a way of getting the column reference dynamically as well. However - this doesn't care what order your indices in sheet1 are in - it just works.